# how can I execute (or ask to be executed) an action from another action file on symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I am making some action files at my part of plugins, the structure is like this:

```
Plugins > My project > modules > mymodule > action > myfileAction.class.php
```

and I am using the default function **public function execute($request)** and what I basically im trying to do is to call another file at same folder, sending parameters to execute a function of it, honestly Ive tried in other ways like `$this->execute('mymodule/myfile2Action');` but no results, and I dont know how to send the paramenters, any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an example of the kind of operation your action would need to perform?

Comment: Why not having all the controller's functions in one file `actions.class.php`? You could execute different functions quite easily then. If the other function you want to call is also an action you can forward to it: `$this->forward('module', 'action')`. The action you forward to will receive the same request object as the first action.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't touched this for a while, but I guess this should help you out:

```
$this->getController()->getPresentationFor($module_name, $action_name);
```

Comment: thanks, but in my case.. getController and getPresentationFor what would it be? getController would be like getMymodule? I getlost in that part because I have no folder "Controllers"